# How to pass a PHP variable to jQuery .append()?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to pass a HTML input fields to the .append() function. I can only PHP for this since the input fields are being re-used in other parts of my application.

Below is my code. Thanks!

```
  $.post("cat_file.php", {menu_cat_id : cat_id })


    .fail(function(){
        alert( "Failed" );
    })

.done(function() {
 $('.menu_item_wrapper[id="'+cat_id+'"]').append(<?php $input_fields ?>);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This explain all, use translate (from russian to your language) http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` the variable out. Assuming the variable is a simple string, or number or whatever.

```
<?php echo $input_fields; ?>
```

You should also take care to put quotes around the PHP you are echoing if you are passing a string to `append()`, or you will end up with a Javascript syntax error.

Comment: Ohh okay. I got it now. Thanks!